# Solidify modifier distorted

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm working on the legs of a garden fireplace, but when I use the solidify modifier to give thickness to the legs, they become very distorted. I hope the image will clarify this bad explanation.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Share the .blend file here, please (using this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: As a BTW, it would usually be a good idea to move the Subsurface modifier to the bottom of the stack, unless there are special reasons (like some uses of shrinkwrapping)  not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling is probably not uniform across the mesh (*i.e.* X, Y and Z have been scaled to different values in object mode), therefore the "Solidify" thickness varies according to direction.

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* to fix this and this should fix the behaviour of Solidify too.

---

Example: the mesh (with solidify) is stretched along a single direction. Solidify gets distorted. Then "Scale" is applied and it gets fixed.

[image]

<sup>*at the end it's not a glitch: it's me comparing the effect before and after*</sup>